# Error on installation of ghc via homebrew

Tags: haskell, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, ghc

hi im not sure what im doing and
basically i tried to get ghc and haskell-platform on to my mac via homebrew
however for reasons that i don't understand, ghc doesn't work hence neither does haskell-platform

according to brew doctor:

```
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
its-fatbass:~ jellynom$ brew doctor
Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fuse.pc
```

but according to someone this can be ignore???
also i cannot seem to find the file to delete it (if i should delete it)

```
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/ghc-7.6.3.mo
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ghc-7.6.3.mountain_lion.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This brew is for GHC only; you might also be interested in haskell-platform.
==> Summary
 /usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.6.3: 5286 files, 776M
its-fatbass:~ jellynom$ brew install haskell-platform
==> Downloading http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/download/2013.2.0.0/haskell-pl
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/haskell-platform/2013.2.0.0
configure: error: Your installation of ghc does not appear to work.
  It cannot compile a simple program (see config.log for the details).
  If you installed ghc from a generic binary tarball then it is worth
  checking that you have the 'gmp' C library and header files installed.
  (On Debian-based systems this package is called libgmp3-dev.)

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/20956
```

i don't know how to check for the gmp c library and header files
and the link they recommended is completely over my head too; something about hscolor missing.

Does this mean i have other things i should have installed prior to installing ghc??? (i have nothing else installed via homebrew other than ghc and haskell-platform)
if so, what should i have installed??

Comment: You can install GMP using `brew install gmp`. You can then try to reinstall GHC. Also if you can find and post the contents of `config.log` it should help to understand what is the problem.

Comment: ahh it think it was the gmp that was missing; it works!! thank youuuu

Comment: even after installing gmp, it still doesn't work.